# How do I access the result of a Select count(*) using an SQLQuery component in Delphi

Tags: sql, delphi, firebird, dbexpress

I am using Delphi RAD Studio 9 and Firebird 2.5

I want to use the count of the number of rows that fit a certain condition.
When I put

```
Select count(*) from VRDB where Lname - 'SMITH'
```

into the the SQL property , upon opening SQLQuert1, I get the error message

> SQLQuery1: Unable to determine field names for %s.

I assume this means  Firebird or Delphi doesn't know what to do with the result.

How do I trap the result of the query? (My query statements work fine using isql.)

Comment: Do you mean "Lname **=** 'SMITH'"?

Comment: You are assuming wrong, this means the SQL or connection is wrong in someway.

Comment: There is no such thing as "Delphi RAD Studio 9". please edit your question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using a Firebird database in Delphi 10 Seattle, the following works fine for me:

```
procedure TForm2.btnCountClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  SqlQuery3.Sql.Text := 'select count(*) from maimages';
  SqlQuery3.Open;
  Caption := IntToStr(SqlQuery3.Fields[0].AsInteger);
end;
```

Btw, which Delphi version do you mean by "RAD Studio 9"?  In case you mean Delphi 2009, the earliest Delphi version I have after D7 is XE4, and the above code also works fine with that.

Answer (score 1):

try to use

```
select count(*) CNT from VRDB where Lname = 'SMITH'
```

Comment: or `select count(*) as counter from VRB...`. (It's a good habit to use `as` to avoid doing this by mistake: `select field1 field2 from tablename`, which I've done far too often) In Delphi `i := sqlQuery.FieldByName('counter').asInteger`

Answer (score 0):

No need to change your query string. Just reference FieldByName ('COUNT').AsInteger.

Comment: Wait a minute. Is that a hyphen?  should be an equal sign.

Comment: use count(*) for field name